# questions about total derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am learning some stuff about the total derivative and got these two questions:

1) I was wondering if a linear map is totally differentiable. So let $A$ be linear, $A\in\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$. Then

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{A(x_0+h)-A(x_0)-A(h)}{\|h\|}=0$$ since $A(x_0+h)=A(x_0)+A(h)$ So $A(x_0)$ is totally differentiable.

Now does it have to be $A'(x_0)=A$ (constant) or $A'(x_0)=A(x_0)$?

2) For a function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$ why is it enough to consider all components $f_1,\dots,f_m$ to show total differentiability?

Thanks!

Comment: About $1$: does $A'(x_0) = A(x_0)$ really make sense? Remember that $A'(x_0)$ is the derivative of $A$ at $x_0$, and this should be a **linear map**. But $A(x_0)$ is the **value** of $A$ at the point $x_0$, which is a vector. Although there are ways to create linear maps from vectors, this is not natural here. So your first guess is correct: $A'(x_0) = A$ (both sides are linear maps here). In particular, this says that the derivative of $A'$, as a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$, is zero, since it is the constant map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for #2, we can show the equivalence of "totally differentiable in each component $\iff$ totally differentiable" as follows: $\Leftarrow$ is perhaps obvious since in the definition we can just take a vector going to $x_0$ along the $i$th axis. $\Rightarrow$ can be shown by taking $\delta_i>0$ such that the value in the $i$th component is less than $\epsilon/\sqrt{m}$, for $\epsilon<1$, then the norm will be less than $\epsilon$ if we choose $\delta \leq \min\limits_{1\leq i\leq m}\delta_i$.